# Is it possible to list my uploaded files?

Tags: support, images

Is there any way to check what files I have uploaded (through my questions or answers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really; we use a global app-level key at http://imgur.com for all images uploaded from our network.

Comment: oh that sucks :( Actually I wanted to refer to one of my answers on SO which I posted a long time ago with an image attachment. Not remembering the name of the Question I wanted to get to my answer by all the files I have uploaded (uploads being fewer than the answers I have posted). Looks like I have to do this the manual way...

Comment: @movie image uploading is only about ~4 months old.. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/